# Как узнать cpuid

Tags: ассемблер

В разных примерах в начале файла .asm указывается тип процессора, то есть к примеру .386 , но как мне узнать свой тип процессора? У меня AMD. Пробовал разными кодами с мсдн и википедии вывести через C++, но там набор цифр и не понятно какой из них нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.386` и прочее - это тип процессора в том ключе, под какой набор инструкций написана программа. Логика очень простая - этот параметр задает семейство процессоров (ну, и соответственно набор инструкций), например, `.386` - 386-ые и выше, `.486` - 486-ые и новее, `.586` - семейство Pentium и новее, `.686p` - семейство Pentium Pro (буковка p означает, что разрешены и привилегированные инструкции). Описание всех этих параметров можно найти в справке к конкретному компилятору. Например, [для MASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t163bt0(VS.71).aspx).

Касательно того что писать - на текущий момент времени проще писать .686p и не задавать лишних вопросов: все равно современный код никто запускать на архаичных компьютерах поколений 386 и 486-х процессоров не будет, тем более, что там даже целевая ОС (под которую пишется программа) не запустится :-) Ну, и, понятно, что разницы Интел или АМД процессор у пользователя нет. Все равно набор инструкций одинаков, если не прибегать к каким-либо специфичным расширениям (типа 3DNow!), наличие которых нужно проверять отдельными способами.